# Grouping Sass Selectors When Using @for

Tags: css, sass

I have a group of heading levels (1 through 6). I am using a @for loop but I can't seem to work out how to group them as one instead of individually.

This is the @for loop I'm using:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
   h#{$i},
   .h#{$i} {
      margin-bottom: $headings-margin-bottom;
      line-height: $headings-line-height;
      font-weight: $headings-font-weight;
      font-family: $headings-font-family;
   }
}
```

Here's what I am expecting:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
   /* styles */
}
```

Here's what is getting compiled:

```
h1 {
   /* styles */
}

h2 {
   /* styles */
}

h3 {
   /* styles */
}

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend/) to join the selectors:

```
%myStyle {
  margin-bottom: $headings-margin-bottom;
  line-height: $headings-line-height;
  font-weight: $headings-font-weight;
  font-family: $headings-font-family;
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
   h#{$i}, .h#{$i} {
      @extend %myStyle;
   }
}
```

The symbol `%` is a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors/), you can use it so `myStyle` will not show up in the compiled `CSS`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much @Arkellys and thank you also for the provided link too :)